# BlockingCollection with Polling Threads grabbing duplicates

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading

I have a blocking collection that is filled with a list of records from a database.

```
Public Shared BatchRecords As IThreadPool(Of BatchRecord) = New IThreadPool(Of BatchRecord)(Function()                                                                                                    Return New BatchRecord                                                                                                End Function, 20)

Public Shared Function GetOne(ThreadName As String) As BatchRecord
     Dim record As BatchRecord = BatchRecords.GetRecord()
     log.WriteLog("Thread:" & ThreadName & " Pool: " & Pool.ToString)
     Return record
End Function

Public Shared Sub AddOne(record As BatchRecord)
    BatchRecords.PutRecord(record)
End Sub

Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                          PoolForBatchRecords()
                      End Sub)

For i As Integer = 0 To 20
    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                              Dim BatchGenerator As New GeneratorThread
                              Thread.CurrentThread.Name = (i + 1).ToString
                              BatchGenerator.Run()
                          End Sub)
Next
```

Inside GeneratorThread

```
Public Function Run()
    while true
        Dim record as MyRecord =  MyCollection.Take()
        'Do Work
    End While
End Function
```

My 20 Tasks are polling for an item from within the BlockingCollection.  But the threads keep getting the same items.  There are no duplicates in the collection. in fact there is only 1 item in the collection when it starts 66879524.

```
Adding BatchId: 66879524 2018/05/29 14:20:01
Thread:1 picking up Batch ID:66879524  2018/05/29 14:20:02
Thread:2 picking up Batch ID:66879524  2018/05/29 14:20:02
Adding BatchId: 66879531 2018/05/29 14:20:02
```

Comment: Are you sure that the collection is filled with different items?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being when adding an item to the list

20 threads all checking for items from the database to process. The check was in a while loop

```
Dim record As BatchRecord = Nothing
Dim keepChecking As Boolean = true
while keepChecking
    'Stop when we find a record
    keepChecking = CheckforWork(byRef record)
End While

BatchRecords.AddOne(record)
```

The while loop should have stopped as soon as it returned false keepChecking but by the time keepChecking was actually set the while loop continued to loop 2-3 more times.

I fixed it by passing in keepChecking byRef which will set the variable to false immediately then returned the record that I found:

```
Dim record As BatchRecord = Nothing
Dim keepChecking As Boolean = true
while keepChecking
    'Stop when we find a record
    record = CheckforWork(byRef keepChecking)
End While
```

This is not exact code of course there are some other checks and a pause between checks as to not hammer the database especially when there are 0 records to be found.